# How to use manual mocking for only one test suite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to run some tests with using manual mocking. I have already mocked a module using the `__mocks__` folder with `jest.mock('../path_of_module/my_module')` or mocking single function with `jest.spyOn()` but they are mocking a function or module for single test or whole file includes my test.

My question is: **how can I mock a function or module for a specific test suite?**

```
describe('Suite 1',function(){

  it('test1', done =>{
    //myAwesomeFunction();
  })
  it('test2', done =>{
    //myAwesomeFunction();
  })
})

describe('Suite 2',function(){

  it('test3', done =>{
    //myAwesomeFunction();
  })
  it('test4', done =>{
    //myAwesomeFunction();
  })
})
```

For example, if these all in same file - how can I mock the `myAwesomeFunction()` for only `testsuite1`?

Comment: Hah I literally have the same question, two hours later!